# Create a new column based on multiple conditions in other columns in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data-wrangling

I have a data frame that has this structure:

```
dat <- data.frame(col1 = sample(0:3, 10, replace = TRUE),
                  col2 = sample(0:3, 10, replace = TRUE))
```

How can I create another column that says 1 if both `col1` and `col2` are not 0 and 2 otherwise?

Thank you!

Comment: `dat %>% mutate(new_col = ifelse(col1 != 0 & col2 != 0, 1, 2))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `case_when` dplyr to solve would be like:

```
dat %>%
  mutate(col3 = case_when(
    col1 != 0 & col2 != 0 ~ 1,
    TRUE ~ 2
  ))
```